# C++ FlagSet: typesafe usage of enumeration as bitset/bitmask

Tags: c++, enum, c++14, type-safety, bitset

Below is my attempt at providing a type-safe way to combine enumeration and bitset together. The resulting class is intended to be use as a set of flags, where each flag is a member of the "user-defined enumeration".

The user must not define any explicit value to the enumeration member.

Below is the "library file" (1 header), followed by a test program providing the usage example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <cassert>

/**
 * FlagSet implements a bitset usable with `enum` and `enum class`.
 *
 * It provide a typesafe interface for manipulating the bitset. This helps
 * prevents mistake as the various operator and function will refuse a
 * parameter that doesn't match the expected enum type.
 *
 * A flagset supports one user-defined enumeration. The number of flags
 * (ie the member of the user enumeration) is not limited, as the underlying
 * bitset (std::bitset) can have an arbitrary large size.
 * 
 * REQUIREMENTS:
 *      * This code source required C++14 to compile.
 *      * The user enumeration shall not explicitely set any value.
 *      * The last enumeration member shall be: "__SENTINEL__"
 *
 */
template<typename T>
struct FlagSet
{
  FlagSet() = default;
  FlagSet(const FlagSet &o) : bitset(o.bitset) {}

  FlagSet &operator|=(const T &val)
  {
    set_true(val);
    return *this;
  }

  FlagSet &operator&=(const T &val)
  {
    bool tmp = bitset[static_cast<utype>(val)] ? true : false;
    bitset.reset();
    bitset[static_cast<utype>(val)] = tmp;
    return *this;
  }

  FlagSet &operator|=(const FlagSet &o)
  {
    bitset |= o.bitset;
    return *this;
  }

  FlagSet &operator&=(const FlagSet &o)
  {
    bitset &= o.bitset;
    return *this;
  }

  FlagSet &operator=(const FlagSet &o)
  {
    bitset = o.bitset;
  }

  /**
   * Return a bitset containing the result of the
   * bitwise AND between *this and val.
   *
   * The resulting bitset can contain at most 1 bit.
   */
  FlagSet operator&(const T&val)
  {
    FlagSet ret(*this);
    ret &= val;

    assert(ret.bitset.count() <= 1);
    return ret;
  }

  /**
   * Perform a AND binary operation between *this and
   * `val` and return the result as a copy.
   */
  FlagSet operator&(const FlagSet &val)
  {
    FlagSet ret(*this);
    ret.bitset &= val.bitset;

    return ret;
  }

  /**
   * Return a bitset containing the result of the
   * bitwise OR between *this and val.
   *
   * The resulting bitset contains at least 1 bit.
   */
  FlagSet operator|(const T&val)
  {
    FlagSet ret(*this);
    ret |= val;

    assert(ret.bitset.count() >= 1);
    return ret;
  }

  /**
   * Perform a OR binary operation between *this and
   * `val` and return the result as a copy.
   */
  FlagSet operator|(const FlagSet &val)
  {
    FlagSet ret(*this);
    ret.bitset |= val.bitset;

    return ret;
  }

  FlagSet operator~()
  {
    FlagSet cp(*this);
    cp.bitset.flip();

    return cp;
  }

  /**
   * The bitset evaluates to true if any bit is set.
   */
  operator bool() const
  {
    return bitset.any();
  }

  /**
   * Below are the method from std::bitset that we expose.
   */

  bool operator==(const FlagSet &o) const
  {
    return bitset == o.bitset;
  }

  std::size_t size() const
  {
    return bitset.size();
  }

  std::size_t count() const
  {
    return bitset.count();
  }

  FlagSet &set()
  {
    bitset.set();
        return *this;
  }

  FlagSet &reset()
  {
    bitset.reset();
        return *this;
  }

  FlagSet &flip()
  {
    bitset.flip();
    return *this;
  }

  FlagSet &set(const T &val, bool value = true)
  {
    bitset.set(static_cast<utype>(val), value);
        return *this;
  }

  FlagSet &reset(const T&val)
  {
    bitset.reset(static_cast<utype>(val));
    return *this;
  }

  FlagSet &flip(const T &val)
  {
    bitset.flip(static_cast<utype>(val));
    return *this;
  }

  bool operator[](const T&val)
  {
    return bitset[static_cast<utype>(val)];
  }

  /**
   * Overload for std::ostream
   */
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const FlagSet& me)
  {
    return stream << me.bitset;
  }

private:
  using utype = std::underlying_type_t<T>;
  std::bitset<static_cast<utype>(T::__SENTINEL__)> bitset;

  void set_true(const T&val)
  {
    bitset[static_cast<utype>(val)] = 1;
  }

};

/**
 * Provide a free operator allowing to combine two enumeration
 * member into a FlagSet.
 */
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum<T>::value, FlagSet<T>>
operator|(const T &lhs, const T &rhs)
{
  FlagSet<T> bs;
  bs |= lhs;
  bs |= rhs;

  return bs;
}
```

Example file:

```
#include "flagset.hpp"

/**
 * Some random enum to use in tests.
 */ 
enum class Options : uint64_t
{
  FULLSCREEN,
    INVERT_MOUSE,
    BLA,
    RED_BACKGROUND,
    RED_FOREGROUND,
    __SENTINEL__
    };


int test_AND()
{
  FlagSet<Options> red(Options::RED_FOREGROUND | Options::RED_BACKGROUND);

  auto ret = red & Options::RED_BACKGROUND;
  assert(ret);
  assert(ret.count() == 1);

  ret = red & Options::RED_FOREGROUND;
  assert(ret);
  assert(ret.count() == 1);

  ret = red & (Options::RED_FOREGROUND | Options::RED_BACKGROUND);
  assert(ret);
  assert(ret.count() == 2);

  ret = ~red & Options::RED_BACKGROUND;
  assert(ret == false);
  assert(ret.count() == 0);
}

int test_OR()
{
  FlagSet<Options> red;
  red |= Options::RED_FOREGROUND | Options::RED_BACKGROUND;
  assert(red.count() == 2);

  FlagSet<Options> opt;
  opt |= (Options::FULLSCREEN | Options::BLA);

  // FULLSCREEN and BLA match, so this evaluates to true.
  assert(opt & (Options::FULLSCREEN | Options::BLA | Options::RED_FOREGROUND | Options::RED_BACKGROUND));

  // Ensure that a group of flag is set
  FlagSet<Options> expected;
  expected |= (Options::FULLSCREEN);
  assert((opt & expected) == expected);

  assert((opt & (Options::RED_FOREGROUND | Options::RED_BACKGROUND)) == false);
  assert((opt & red) == false);

  assert(!(opt & Options::INVERT_MOUSE));
  opt |= ~red;
  assert(opt & Options::INVERT_MOUSE);
}

int test_set_reset()
{
  FlagSet<Options> opt;

  assert(opt.count() == 0);
  opt.set();
  assert(opt.count() == opt.size() && opt.size() == 5);
  opt.reset();
  assert(opt.count() == 0);

  opt.set(Options::BLA);
  assert(opt.count() == 1 && opt[Options::BLA]);
  opt.set(Options::BLA, false);
  assert(opt.count() == 0);  
}

int test_type_safety()
{
  // The following will not compile.
  FlagSet<Options> bs;

  // bs & 42;
  // bs &= 42;
  // bs |= 42;
  // bs | 42;
}

int main()
{
  auto t = std::bitset<4>();
  assert((int)Options::FULLSCREEN == 0);
  test_AND();
  test_OR();
  test_set_reset();
}
```

I am interested in pretty much all feedback: from implementation details, to API as well as naming (FlagSet being the best name I could come up with).

Comment: Very nice, but that `__SENTINEL__`  threw me off when I first spotted in the class. Until I saw the usage example, I thought that you were relying on some obscure corner of your compiler. Names using double underscore are only meant to be used for compiler/standard-library names: http://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/1198654

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This looks pretty good. I'd propose the following.

First, you use `set_value` in exactly one place. It's a pretty unnecessary function, and just this would suffice:

```
FlagSet &operator|=(const T &val)
{
    bitset.set(static_cast<utype>(val));
    return *this;
}
```

Second, for `&=`, the expression `expr ? true : false` is an antipattern that can be replaced with just `expr`. In this case, you don't even need that as `bitset` provides [`test`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/set). The whole thing can become:

```
FlagSet &operator&=(const T &val)
{
    bool tmp = bitset.test(static_cast<utype>(val));
    bitset.reset();
    bitset.set(static_cast<utype>(val), tmp);
    return *this;
}
```

Third, you're missing a `return`:

```
FlagSet &operator=(const FlagSet &o)
{
    bitset = o.bitset;
    return *this; // <== 
}
```

But really, since these are trivial, pretty to `default` them:

```
FlagSet(const FlagSet& ) = default;
FlagSet& operator=(const FlagSet& ) = default;
```

Or don't even specify them.

Fourth, prefer to make `operator bool` explicit:

```
explicit operator bool() const
{
    return bitset.any();
}
```

That will prevent weird expressions like `FlagSet{} + 4` from compiling.

Lastly, `__SENTINEL__` is a reserved word in the C++ Standard. You could instead require it to be named something else, like `LAST_VALUE` or `MAX_VALUE` or something.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but the use of `__SENTINEL__` could be alleviated by using `sizeof(std::underlying_type_t<T>) * 8` instead.

Comment: @MarkIngram Or `sizeof(std::underlying_type_t<T>)*CHAR_BIT` just to be safe? :)

Comment: It's missing a few `const` as well (e.g. `operator|`)

Comment: Finally, I propose adding a non-explicit conversion from T to FlagSet<T> so you can easily construct from a single flag. Don't know why I'm not putting these things in a fresh answer really

Comment: FWIW dropping `__SENTINEL__` _[sic]_ works great, at the cost of potentially wider bitsets than are usually necessary (but I think it's worth it)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well this is an unexpected influx of activity on a 3.5-year-old answer?

Comment: @Barry Luck of the draw - there was some discussion on how best to accomplish exactly `FlagSet` and a bit of Googling found this gem ^_^

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit @MarkIngram That could work but would require the underlying type to be properly selected. You could write `enum class MyEnumWith10Values : uint8_t {...};` because the values would range from 0 to 9, but then you would still need a 10 bits `std::bitset<10>`. So you'd have to be sure to write `enum class MyEnumWith10Values: uint16_t {...};` instead. It would also put a 64 limit on the number of possible enum entry.

Comment: @Xaqq I have since realised that the `sizeof(underlying_type_t<T>)*CHAR_BIT` choice is wrong - it represents the number of bits taken up by a value of the underlying type, rather than the actual maximum value of the underlying type, which could be substantially higher. I was previously fine with having unused bits (your comment suggests you are set on having no unused bits - why?) but this factor kind of blows that up a bit. Perhaps the sentinel value is the easiest way after all.

Comment: As proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31906371/258772), using `std::bitset<std::numeric_limits<utype>::max()>` is a way to get rid of `__SENTINEL__`. However, that will have obvious drawbacks like breaking `set()`.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, @Xaqq, this is really nice!

I published the code in [GitHub](https://github.com/mrts/flag-set-cpp) with amendments from @Barry and @lightness-races-in-orbit and minor modifications, usage is as follows:

```cpp
#include "flag_set.hpp"

enum class Options : uint8_t {
    FULLSCREEN,
    INVERT_MOUSE,
    FLASH,
    RED_BACKGROUND,
    RED_FOREGROUND,
    _
};

int main()
{
    flag_set<Options> red(Options::RED_FOREGROUND | Options::RED_BACKGROUND);

    if (red & Options::RED_BACKGROUND)
        cout << "Red background activated";
}
```

Note that I chose `_` as sentinel as it stands out clearly and is unlikely to collide with a real enum value. Also, I felt that it is natural to follow the ISO standard library underscore style naming as this is a general utility class similar to standard library classes.

Please feel free to file further amendments as issues in the GitHub repository. @Xaqq, if you want to, I can yield the repository to you as you are the rightful author.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

```cpp
// Operator that combines two enumeration values into a flag_set.
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum<T>::value, flag_set<T>> operator|(const T& lhs, const T& rhs)
```

adds `operator|` to all enums, including those that don't have the expected special sentinel.

This breaks e.g. Qt's `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE()` macro.

This can be fixed with

```cpp
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_enum_that_contains_sentinel :
    std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_enum_that_contains_sentinel<T, decltype(static_cast<void>(T::_))> :
    std::is_enum<T> {};

// Operator that combines two enumeration values into a flag_set only if the
// enumeration contains the sentinel `_`.
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<is_enum_that_contains_sentinel<T>::value, flag_set<T>>
    operator|(const T& lhs, const T& rhs)
{
    ...
```

(Based on Jonathan Müller's [code](https://github.com/foonathan/type_safe/blob/master/include/type_safe/flag_set.hpp#L24-L26) and available in [GitHub](https://github.com/mrts/flag-set-cpp/blob/master/include/flag_set.hpp#L156-L177).)